# Can I shorten an if/else statement with lambda?

Tags: c#, if-statement, lambda

I have the following statement as part of building a datarow for a datatable and I was wondering if I could shorten it using a lambda statement or anything more elegant.

```
if (outval(line.accrued_interest.ToString()) == true) 
{ 
temprow["AccruedInterest"] = line.accrued_interest; 
} 
else 
{
temprow["AccruedInterest"] = DBNull.Value;
}
```

The statement is checked by:

```
 public static bool outval(string value)
        {
            decimal outvalue;
            bool suc = decimal.TryParse(value, out outvalue);
            if (suc)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }


        }
```

Comment: `return decimal.TryParse(value, out outvalue);`

Comment: @SLaks, thanks, I'm not worried by the string validity checking (outval function), rather by the making the if/else statement more readable as I have to do that many times.  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: `string x = 1 == 1 ? "yes it does" : "no it doesn't";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static bool outval(string value)
{
    decimal outvalue;
    return decimal.TryParse(value, out outvalue);
}

temprow["AccruedInterest"] = outval(line.accrued_interest.ToString()) ? (object)line.accrued_interest : (object)DBNull.Value;
```

**Edit:**
casting to `object` is important since `?:` ternary operator needs to return results both true case and false case has to be implicitly converted to other. I don't know what is type of `accrued_interest` I assume it will be a `double` or `decimal` since there is no implicit conversion between `decimal` and `DBNull`. In order to make it work you've to cast to `object` type.
Is that clear?

Comment: Yes, that is the business @sriram-sakthivel  That works perfectly.  Can you explain why the "(object) statement is important?

Comment: The ? operator (see my post for the link) expects the same type, and DBNull.Value is not the same type as a string

Answer (score 4):

You want the ?  Operator, you don't need a lambda expression.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

```
int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string classify;

// if-else construction.
if (input < 0)
    classify = "negative";
else
    classify = "positive";

// ?: conditional operator.
classify = (input < 0) ? "negative" : "positive";
```

Comment: I'm sure about a hundred other people will also be happy to tell you this in the next 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call a separate method. No need of method or any other things

```
decimal result;   
if(decimal.TryParse(line.accrued_interest.ToString(),out result))
 temprow["AccruedInterest"] = line.accrued_interest
else
 temprow["AccruedInterest"] = DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: +1 There's no reason to make this more complicated than it should be. You may want to mention to the OP that instead of assigning `line.accrued_interest`, a `string`, he may be better off assigning `result`, a decimal, if the schema requires a decimal there.

Answer (score 0):

Also,

```
public static bool outval(string value)
{
    decimal outvalue;
    bool suc = decimal.TryParse(value, out outvalue);
    if (suc)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

To..

```
public static bool outval(string value)
{
    decimal outvalue;
    return decimal.TryParse(value, out outvalue);
}
```